# How to Achieve retry Mechanism in C# MS Framework

Tags: c#, retry-logic

we want to implement a functionality which reattempts the execution of failed test scripts. This needs to be implemented at Solution or framework level so functionality is available for all the projects. Following needs to be taken care.
1.  If a test script fails, it will be re-executed for x times
2.  X will configurable in app config file. If set 0 there will be no re-attempt
3.  A column '# of Reattempts' will be added after Status in Extent Reports below which will indicate the # of re-attempts made before the script was finally passed/failed.

Comment: what's executing the scripts?

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Also what do you mean with _"test script"_

Comment: The whole concept seems flawed to me. Tests should be consistent. Instead of looking into what is causing the tests to fail you are looking into a retry mechanism... This is a XY problem to me.